# Prefix every key with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am parsing a `package.json` file and pulling out all the dependencies that start with `@example`.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "dependencies": { 
    "@example/alpha" : "1.2.3",
    "@example/bravo" : "1.2.3",
    "@example/charlie" : "1.2.3"
  }
}
```

The following is working fine.

```bash
jq -r '.dependencies | select(. != null) | with_entries(select(.key | contains("@example")))' package.json
```

This gives me:

```
{ 
  "@example/alpha" : "1.2.3",
  "@example/bravo" : "1.2.3",
  "@example/charlie" : "1.2.3"
}
```

However I also need to transform the keys, by adding a prefix of `**/`, so that I end up with:

```
{ 
  "**/@example/alpha" : "1.2.3",
  "**/@example/bravo" : "1.2.3",
  "**/@example/charlie" : "1.2.3"
}
```

**How can I add the prefix to every key?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify `.key` inside your `with_entries` just as you can filter on it:

```
jq -r '
  .dependencies
  | select(. != null)
  | with_entries(
      select(.key | contains("@example"))
      | .key |= "**/\(.)"
    )' package.json
```

Comment: `.dependencies // {}` probably makes more sense than `.dependencies | select(. != null)` (since you end up with `{}` rather than nothing if there are no dependencies). (I realize you inherited this from the OP.)